# Creating a child-class object on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested, show

In my rails application I have a Program that has many `Enterprises`.

In my program/show, I want to have the option to simply create a new `Enterprise` that belongs to the program shown.

I tried using nested resources and a routing helper like `new_program_enterprise_path`, but it gave me the `No route matches "{:action=>"new", :controller=>"enterprises"}"` error.

This is what my `routes.rb` has:

```
resources :programs do
    resources :enterprises
end
```

Comment: post your `rake routes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are using the routing helper. The `new_program_enterprise_path` should take an instance of `Program` in its parameters like this `new_program_enterprise_path(@program)` this would result to a path that looks like this
`/programs/:program_id/enterprises/new`.

Comment: that helps a lot, thanks! but how can i get that @program as a parameter in the enterprises/new view to set it as the new enterprise program?

Comment: for example, when I put `<%= @enterprise.program %>` at the view, it doesn't return anything, as it's a nill value... @pedro